# double and Integer conversion

Tags: java, casting, autoboxing

I am trying to figure this out:

```
double chiSquare = ((double)(hashtable.get(key).intValue()/noWords))/* * Math.log10((NO_DOCUMENTS/all.get(key)))*/;
if (key.equals("love")){
    System.out.println(hashtable.get(key));
    System.out.println(all.get(key));                
    System.out.println(noWords);    
    System.out.println(chiSquare);
    System.out.println((double)1/841);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Why is it printing chiSquare, prints a zero, while printing 1/841 gives the double value?
The hashtable is of `<String, Integer>`

Comment: (double)(1/841) == 0, but (double)1/841 == 1.0/841. You can figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @GregS indicated in his comment, an int divided by an int is an int.
Casting one of the numbers to a double will produce the output your desire.

```
double chiSquare = ((double)hashtable.get(key).intValue())/noWords;
```

Or, use the convenience method on Integer to convert it to a double:

```
double chiSquare = hashtable.get(key).doubleValue()/noWords;
```

Comment: `Integer#doubleValue()` is definitely the way to go. +1

Answer (score 1):

Because the parentheses are incorrect.

```
double chiSquare = ( (double) hashtable.get(key).intValue() )/noWords;
```